# How do I remove the "keep me logged in" checkbox on the facebook login page?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have a financial services web application that is requesting access to a user's FB page, but being logged into facebook is not sufficient to be considered authenticated on our site.  When the user clicks the button to invoke FB.login, the window that appears contains a checkbox that says Keep me logged in to .  Is there any way I can prevent this from appearing so as not to confuse users?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

by default i dont think facebook jive you the option to hide this checkbox, but if you have control over where the login for appears you could probably hide it using CSS and display:none on the element that hold the checkox.

not sure how doing so will sit with the facebook api terms though.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't hide that, its part of the standard Facebook login screen.  But a significant majority of the time people won't even see that first screen because they are already logged into Facebook and will only get the authorize your application prompt.